# Align left edges of vertical views in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

How can I make the `500 (TextView)` match the left edge of `checkbox` above ?

I am using `RelativeLayout`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/group_indicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/expander_open_holo_dark" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/GroupCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:scaleX="2"
    android:scaleY="2" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/GroupSeekbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/GroupSeekCount"
    android:layout_below="@id/lblListHeader"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:max="1000"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" >
</SeekBar>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/GroupSeekCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" 
    android:text="500"
    android:layout_below="@id/GroupCheckBox"

    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/group_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/expander_open_holo_dark" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/GroupCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleX="2"
        android:scaleY="2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/group_indicator"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/GroupCheckBox"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/GroupSeekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:max="1000"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/GroupCheckBox"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/lblListHeader"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/GroupSeekCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/GroupCheckBox"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/GroupSeekbar"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="500"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. Though this is same as suggested by Evan. I was looking to use RelativeLayout only

Comment: now i edited my ans i have done your requirement using RelativeLayout so please check out this.

Comment: This works great .. Can you tell me the key piece I was missing. There seem to be lot of changes to the layout.

Comment: RelativeLayout always work on based on reference of each other view.

Answer (score 1):

I would go about this much differently.

Try grouping the expander and list header into a horizontal linearlayout, then group the Checkbox and 500 text into a vertical linearlayout. Finally, these two linearlayout's should be nested within a horizontal linearlayout.

Comment: I could do that but I wanted to keep it in single Viewgroup for performance reasons

Comment: Ok, then please try making a static width for the checkbox and 500 text, the paddingRight will then be off a matching width, and they should line up fine.

Comment: Is there a way, I can make the width of 500 textview equal to checkbox without hardcoding it. I am concerned hardcoding it will not scale it properly on different displays

Comment: I honestly wouldn't worry about it, try and find the width of it by testing different static widths. You're using dp, so it will be fine regardless of device.

Answer (score 1):

First define the CheckBox, only THEN the TextView.
And then set the TextView's layout_width to match_parent (so that it takes the remaining space)

Also, the ImageView can become part of the TextView (compound drawable), to reduce the controls count:
To do so: in the TextView definition, set these attributes:

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/expander_open_holo_dark"
android:drawablePadding="8dp"
```

Then you can modify the group indicator by code:

```
Drawable drw = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.expander_open_holo_dark);
lblListHeader.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drw, null, null, null);
```

Even better (always bearing in mind the purpose to optimize the design), you could use a CheckedTextView control, so to have the image, the text and the checkmark in a single control (since it extends the TextView, it can hold compound drawables as well as the TextView does).

Of course, you can move the tick mark to the right.

Comment: The 500 TextView is defined last. 500 is in next row, If I set it to 500 , it goes to extreme left.

Comment: So! it's "GroupSeekCount" - well, I didn't understand the question properly. So, very simply, align it (optionally) to the parent's bottom AND to the CheckBox Left. Done.